# How can i stop jquery .append() from randomising the order of the elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this very basic script that grabs image data from url and displays information about the image in an li. The script does work and the `wallpaper` function is called about 10 times but every time the page is reloaded the order of the li items changes. Is there any way to fix that?

Here is the script, sorry for the messy code:

```
//wallpaper info mainlist ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function wallpaper(url){
var id1= url.replace("https://drive.google.com/file/d/", "");
var id= id1.replace("/view?usp=sharing", "");
var mainlink =    "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=";
var thumbnail =   "https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=";
var download =    "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=";

$.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/" + id + "?key=------", function (gotData) {
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  

//calculate date---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
myDate =           new Date(gotData.createdDate.slice(0, 10));
var options =      { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
var name=          gotData.originalFilename.slice(0, -4);
var maindata=      'File Size: ' + bytesToSize(gotData.fileSize) + '<br><br><br><br>' + 'Upload Date: ' + myDate.toLocaleString("en-US", options) + '<br><br><br><br>' + 'Wallpaper Dimensions: ' + gotData.imageMediaMetadata.width + 'x' + gotData.imageMediaMetadata.height;

//append data---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$('.mainlist').append("<li><a href='"+mainlink+id+"' data-lightbox='wallpaper1'><img class='icon' src='"+thumbnail+id+"'></a ><span>"+name+"</span><img class='button1' src='/images/info.png'><a href='#'><img class='button2' src='/images/download.png'></a><ul class='dropmenu'><p>"+maindata+"</p></ul>");


//ajax request--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var http =        new XMLHttpRequest();
var links =       { main: mainlink + id, thumb: thumbnail + id, dnload: encodeURIComponent(download) + id };
var data =        { Size: 'FileSize: ' + bytesToSize(gotData.fileSize), UploadDate: 'Upload Date: ' + myDate.toLocaleString("en-US", options), WallpaperDimensions: 'Wallpaper Dimensions: ' + gotData.imageMediaMetadata.width + 'x' + gotData.imageMediaMetadata.height };
var name =        { wallname: name };
var datajson =    JSON.stringify(data);
var linksjson =   JSON.stringify(links);
var namejson =    JSON.stringify(name);

http.open("POST", 'walldb.php', true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.onload = function () {

      if (this.status == 200) {
        //console.log(this.responseText)
      }
    }
    http.send("links=" + linksjson + "&data=" + datajson + "&name=" + namejson);
})
}



//mainlist---------------------------------------
wallpaper("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a4mib5pVOGIzBTxjGmvVwx-0uvK2NqaR/view?usp=sharing");
//-----------------------------------------------
wallpaper('https://drive.google.com/file/d/11xvntovifR7x6888LUcCKKCVhijwuds4/view?usp=sharing');
//-----------------------------------------------
wallpaper('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JPN3uk5V_9z1i6RggiKFvAmX32Rz2uyC/view?usp=sharing');
//-----------------------------------------------
wallpaper('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XdbEAMkm08qVC6k7AV3iE6Z1_XCwRgLU/view?usp=sharing');
//-----------------------------------------------
wallpaper('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pgpRKV5GG2ANUec4QM5e0Lmo574vfRiM/view?usp=sharing');
//-----------------------------------------------
wallpaper('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XDKdp1weajeKZyg6ai-cr0b-PRnyJqJ1/view?usp=sharing');
//-----------------------------------------------
wallpaper('https://drive.google.com/file/d/17YReCJoHa9MYrDMYjrPlMC_3cWuO5pIw/view?usp=sharing');
//-----------------------------------------------
wallpaper('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zuX4j6FAEDyH0L-0RwhxCqh5Or8BY_9Z/view?usp=sharing');
//-----------------------------------------------
wallpaper('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_iTXhka08y2f1UQHTulBayakSp-Ogn4f/view?usp=sharing');
//-----------------------------------------------
wallpaper('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KAwemGXYHVwwPoaH2kL2-4UwxNgh6jDz/view?usp=sharing');
```

Comment: You can either create all `<li>`s in advance, or you can use `Promise.all` and wait for the inital `getJSON`s to finish before running the main (synchronous, ordered) part of the code

Comment: how do i do the `promise.all` method? sorry i am really new to javascript

Answer (score 0):

For the `Promise.all` method, because you need both the response object (you call it `gotData`) *and* something related to the URL, the general idea is to call `.promise()` on the `getJSON` call, and chain a `.then` onto it which repackages the response into the data and the URL that you need. Then call `Promise.all` on an array of those Promises, and the responses will all be parsed at once, once each of them comes back:

```
function wallpaper(url) {
  var id1 = url.replace("https://drive.google.com/file/d/", "");
  var id = id1.replace("/view?usp=sharing", "");
  return $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/" + id + "?key=------")
    .promise()
    .then(response => ({ response, id }));
}

Promise.all(
    wallpaper("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a4mib5pVOGIzBTxjGmvVwx-0uvK2NqaR/view?usp=sharing"),
    wallpaper('https://drive.google.com/file/d/11xvntovifR7x6888LUcCKKCVhijwuds4/view?usp=sharing'),
    wallpaper('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JPN3uk5V_9z1i6RggiKFvAmX32Rz2uyC/view?usp=sharing'),
    // ...
  )
  .then((arr) => {
    arr.forEach(processResponse);
  });

function processResponse({ response, id }) {
  var mainlink = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=";
  var thumbnail = "https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=";
  var download = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=";

  var myDate = new Date(gotData.createdDate.slice(0, 10));
  // etc
```